# Xcode 10 “appletv is busy: Preparing debugger support for apple tv”

Tags: xcode, apple-tv

I am trying to connect via network to an AppleTV 4k in Xcode. The pair does succesfully, but is remaining in a loop saying “apple tv is busy: Preparing debugger support for apple tv”.

My Xcode version is 10.1 and my Apple TV's version is 12.1.1.

What I have done:

1. in Devices and Simulators I clicked on + button and clicked on my
   apple tv, clicked on Done, happened nothing
2. I unpaired the devices and paired them again, happened nothing
3. I cleaned the build folder,same
4. I waited more than 20 minutes, same
5. I waited 15-20 minutes, restarted Xcode, same

I do not know what to try anymore.

Comment: Any luck here?   I am stuck in the same point

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not find any solution, I changed the network that I was using for both AppleTV and Mac and I unpaired and paired again the Xcode with AppleTV and it worked.

Comment: omg I just put my Macbook close to the Apple TV device, and the pairing successfully finished

Answer (score 2):

For me it just took a long time - in case you are also connected via an ethernet cable try to remove ethernet from your Mac and from the Apple tv - it seems the data transfer only takes place over Wifi.

In the Activity Monitor you can monitor the network usage of Xcode - you'll see that it is transferring data, even if the UI in Xcode seems to hang.

BTW: Transferring the iOS system files from the Apple TV to the computer on first connect is about 1.6GB of data, that's why it will take some time ...

Note:
I just found out you can also connect the AppleTV directly via IP address in Xcode -> Devices. Just right click on the AppleTV, choose `Connect with IP Address`and enter the address you see on the apple tv's settings -> network page. At least running your app then also works when the Mac and the tv are connected by ethernet - it might also speed up the setup.

Comment: How long can it take if Apple TV is going to sleep after some time, should i change sleep time to "never"?

Comment: Couldn't connect with IP address.

Comment: There's no option "Connect with IP Address"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & this worked for my IOS app, but I don't know if it works for AppleTV.

1. Drag & Drop your .app file to Desktop/any other folder so it is easily found

[Finding the .app file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogH7o.png)

[.app file on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBIPf.png)

2. Window -> Devices and Simulators

[Device & Simulators/InstalledApps/+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thodD.png)

Here you should see your device.

3. Click on the "+" below "INSTALLED APPS"
4. Select the file you just dragged & dropped to desktop

Now your app you app should start installing

Hope it works :)

P.S.: I can't directly attack screenshots because I'm a new user....